# duda sobre rango de lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for i in range(0,len(abc),3):
    abc.remove(abc[i])
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

he probado imprimiendo el valor de la variable i  y eliminando manual con ese mismo valor los elementos de la lista y funciona. Sin embargo este codigo funciona:

```
for i in range(len(alphabet), 1, -1):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        alphabet.pop(i-1)
```

por lo que entiendo hace lo mismo pero en orden invertido.

ALguien podria hacerme abrir las ojos un poco sobre ello, no entiendo la logica de que tengo mal.

Comment: Es porque `i` se va incrementando mientras `abc` va disminuyendo de tamaño porque le estas quitando elementos, en algún momento va a dar ese error. Asi que hacerlo de forma inversa no es descabellado, ya que el índice `i` decrece a medida que disminuye `abc`.

Comment: usando el metodo pop si tiene logica ir en reversa, pero remove busca por valor, por eso cambie de pop a remove

Comment: Los valores que pones en el `range(0, len(abc), 3)` se calculan sólo una vez, antes de empezar la iteración. Aún si `abc` cambia dentro del ciclo, el rango seguirá igual.

Comment: se calculan una vez mientras que el bucle se repite? por eso remove no encontraria dentro del rango el valor que le asigno, porque al eliminar y dar el nuevo(que ya tenia guardado desde el principio) se va de rango, entiendo entiendo, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso el error se da debido a que estas disminuyendo el tamaño original de la lista mientras lo vas recorriendo, por lo que el valor del index en un determinado momento pasa a ser superior que el tamaño de la lista.

abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

Al principio abc posee un largo de 27, por cada iteración se reduce 1 el tamaño de la lista y se agregan 3 al index, por lo que

Comprensión visual de lo que esta sucediendo:

posición index => 0  => 3  => 6  => 9  => 12 => 15 => 18 => **21** => 24 => 27

tamaño lista   => 27 => 26 => 25 => 24 => 23 => 22 => 21 => **20** **Error: Index out of range**

Debido a que la lista posee 20 elementos y el index iría por la posición número 21.

De la 2da manera propuesta no da error, ya que el index nunca sería mayor al tamaño de la lista, dado que se reduce en vez de aumentar, siendo un mejor acercamiento a la solución.

Espero que se haya entendido y te sirva!

Answer (score -2):

creo que lo que pasa es que por el método Remove() no podes eliminar elementos de una lista mediante el un índice, sino que podes eliminar un elemento específico de una lista, no utilizar una variable y hacer que recorra la lista.
Sin embargo como en este caso lo que queres es eliminar un elemento mediante el índice, recorriendo la lista mediante la variable[i] debes utilizar el método pop.

Comment: a remove le doy el valor de i(ejemplo: 'a') en ese momento, a los que deberia de eliminar el primer valor que coincida, por eso desisti de intentar hacerlo con pop, ya que trabaja con indices y la lista se seguia modificando

Comment: Totalmente equivocado.